# Show $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{E_n}gdm=0\mbox{.}$

Tags: proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Show that if $g$ is summable on $A$ and $A\supset E_1 \supset E_2,\ldots$ and $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n= \emptyset$ then

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{E_n}gdm=0\mbox{.}$$

Proof: Assume the contrary. So there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $N\in \mathbb{N}$ there is $n>N$ such that $$\Big |\int_{E_n}gdm \Big| \ge \epsilon \mbox{.}$$
But that also means that for every $N=1,2,\ldots$ there is $n>N$ such that $E_n$ is not empty. Contradiction with $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n= \emptyset$.

Is this a correct "proof"? Would you add anything?

Comment: Let $E_n=(0,\frac{1}{n}).$ Then $\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n=\emptyset$ but for every $n,$ there exists $N\ge n$ such that $E_N\not=\emptyset.$

Comment: @awllower ok, so my attempt is clearly wrong

Comment: This is an invalid proof, since the $E_n$s may all be non-empty.

Comment: A suggestion: Maybe you can use the monotonicity of the Lebesgue integral, and try to prove that, in the case here, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{E_n}gdm=\int_{\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}gdm.$

Answer (score 2):

In your attempt, you did not use the integrability of $g$ (and the sets $E_n$ may have all positive measure).

Here are some hints:

- if $g$ is the indicator function of a measurable set, then the result is a consequence of properties of a measure.
- When $g$ is a linear combination of indicator functions of a measurable sets, it is just linearity of the limit.
- If $g$ is non-negative and integrable, approximate it by functions like in the second bullet.
- Write $g$ as the difference of two non-negative integrable functions.

Alternatively, if you know the monotone convergence theorem, you can use it with $f_n:=|g|-|g|\mathbf 1(E_n)$.

Comment: nice................+1 @Davide

Comment: The first two bullet points are clear to me, but I don't know about the third and fourth ones..

Comment: Do you know that a non-negative measurable function is a pointwise increasing limit of linear combination of indicator functions?

Comment: Yes, I remember that result was proven on my course. But we called linear combination of indicator fucntions as SIMPLE functions. Is this different?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Please help me... :(

Comment: Yes, I could have used the terminology of simple functions. Maybe the third step is not necessary if you know that the Lebesgue integral of a function $g$ is the supremum of the integral of non-negative simple functions which are smaller than $g$.